# Magento - many of same cache requests

Tags: performance, magento, caching

today I realized that the Magento doest a lot of same requests to my memcached server, it's requesting the key **Zend_LocaleC_en_GB_currencynumber_** . Do you anyone know where is it generated and how can I improve it? It's probably somehow related to rendering of price box but I dont see reason why it's 50 times in a page. Thanks, Jaro.

Edited:
So far I did quick fix
Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached::load

```
public function load($id, $doNotTestCacheValidity = false)
{
    if ( isset($GLOBALS[$id]) ) {
        return $GLOBALS[$id];
    }

    $tmp = $this->_memcache->get($id);
    if (is_array($tmp) && isset($tmp[0])) {
        $GLOBALS[$id] = $tmp[0];
        return $tmp[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's not nice but seems to be working. At least many of requests agains memcached server disappeared. Jaro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of the known issues in Zend Framework community. It even was reported as an improvement for 1.0.3 release (http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2311).

You fix make sense for Magento where a lot of calls to Zend_Currency is performed and connection to memcached having some limitations or slow enough.

For instance on most of the projects we are using memcached and haven't experienced too big loss in page load time with this calls.

However you can fix it in Magento to make a workaround with ZF:

1. Rewrite core/locale model in your module
2. Override currency() method

   ```
   public function currency($currency)
   {
        if (!isset(self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency])) {
           $currencyObject = parent::currency($currency);
           $currencyObject->setFormat(array(
               'format' => Zend_Locale_Data::getContent($this->getLocale(), 'currencynumber')
           ));
           return $currencyObject;
        }
        return parent::currency($currency);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think it make sense to save any milisecond which is easy to reach. SO this should be definitely a part of core fix.

Comment: @Jaro since this bug was marked as won't fix in ZF, it is possible that core team will just ignore it, they don't see such minor improvements noticeable, especially for enterprise customers who have FPC module..